# The SAML authentication request had a NameID Policy that could not be satisfied.

Tags: windows-server-2016, adfs, saml

I'm using Issuance Policy as:

**Rule 1:**

[image]

**Rule 2 (custom):**

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", 
Issuer = c.Issuer, 
OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, 
Value = c.Value, 
ValueType = c.ValueType,
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient", 
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/namequalifier"] = "https://fs.hhres.com/adfs/services/trust", 
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/spnamequalifier"] = "sp_test");
```

When I try to login, it gives me error (from Event Viewer)-

> The SAML authentication request had a NameID Policy that could not be
>   satisfied.
>
> Requestor: BambooHR-SAML
>
> Name identifier format:
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress 
>   SPNameQualifier:
>
> Exception details:  MSIS7070: The SAML request contained a
>   NameIDPolicy that was not satisfied by the issued token. Requested
>   NameIDPolicy: AllowCreate: True Format:
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
>   SPNameQualifier: . Actual NameID properties: Format:
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient, NameQualifier:
>   https://adfs_url/adfs/services/trust SPNameQualifier: sp_test,
>   SPProvidedId: .
>
> This request failed.
>
> User Action  Use the AD FS Management snap-in to configure the
>   configuration that emits the required name identifier.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by changing the line-

```
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient",
```

into

```
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress",
```

Comment: Yup - that would work as well. Re. above - Incoming : select email Outgoing : select NameID. That allows the format box for editing - select email. This way is far easier then writing "Properties".

Comment: It didn't work and gives same error. That make my rule as: `c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress");
`

Answer (score 0):

It wants a NameID format of emailAddress and you are supplying one of transient.

The easiest way to do this is via a Transform rule.

Transform email to NameID and pick email format from the drop-down.

Comment: When I select "Transform an Incoming Claim", it gives many textboxes `Incoming Claim Type`, `Incoming name ID format`, `Outgoing Claim Type` and `Outgoing name ID format`. Can you please update your answer with the values that should be used in each of them?